# Select default value based on my DB value in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

Am working on a edit profile screen where am using a popup for edit. In this i want to select a an option based on my DB value. My code goes as shown below..

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="usertypeselected.BranchID" class="col s10" name="branchid" 
                                        ng-options="branchdetails.id as branchdetails.branch_city for branchdetails in lspuserbranchmapdata">
                                </select>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.editItem = function editItem(item) {
            $scope.editingItem = { fname: item.a_firstname,
                                   lname: item.a_lastname,
                                   password: item.a_password,
                                   username: item.a_username,
                                   address: item.a_email,
                                   acive: item.a_active,
                                   BranchID:item.a_branchid
                                    };
            $scope.usertypeselected.selectedBranchID = item.a_branchid;
```

Am able to bind all text fields but. am unable to bind select field.

lspuserbranchmapdata - contains all the objects for selectbox
BranchID - is the id to be selected from lspuserbranchmapdata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it the issue was with the framework i was using: 
Details :- Slim framework cache had previous data which was reflecting because of which data was not binding. Thanks for the thoughts over the problem :)